# child subprocess kill in python daemon

Tags: python, subprocess, daemon

I have damon in python which runs external program:

```
subprocess.call(["java", "-jar", "start.jar"])
```

when I kill daemon, the child process (java) is still running

how can I make so that child process is also killed ?

Comment: How are you killing the daemon?  If you use kill -9, there's nothing you can do, but otherwise you could probably write a signal handler for that signal, catch it to kill the java process, and then exit gracefully.

Answer (score 8):

Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.call()`. For example:

```
import subprocess
my_process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'])
```

To terminate the child:

```
my_process.kill()
```

To capture the kill signal, you could so something like this:

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```