# Command Line Execution in Python with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/python-subprocess)
>   [child subprocess kill in python daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114812/child-subprocess-kill-in-python-daemon)

How can I run commands in the windows command line through python?

I'm trying to have it so that it starts a subprocess, I don't care about the output, but I want to be able to kill it at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subprocess.Popen:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I'd rather `subprocess.call` http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call